# Can't find "android application" in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I can't find "Android Application" in Visual Studio. Where is it?

[image: New Project dialog]

Comment: What happens if you pick Android in that list what do you see?

Comment: This : http://postimg.org/image/8hfln9jfj/

Comment: And what happens if you pick the blank android app, is that not what you want?

Comment: This is what should be : http://postimg.org/image/8b912lmhz/

Comment: A lot has changed with recent versions of Xamarin, are you sure it should *still* be like that?

Comment: All the Image links Redirect to pr0n on my iPhone. Should I clear my cookies?

Comment: I think you're right "blank android app" is what I was looking for.
Probably I need version that costs money (Business or higher) 
Thanks anyway

Comment: @UweKeim No, you're right, the site chosen by the OP posts extra images at the bottom.

Comment: @Alex You should pick a different image posting site in the future, like [imgur](http://imgur.com/)

Comment: Thanks, @lasse. Maybe we both should clear our browser cookies ;-)

Comment: I had to visit a java site as well, so I already did.